# How to get the default font size of control as a static variable?

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to scale the picture in the GeometryCollection to the default font size of the Button control, except, I want to do this statically based on a default font, not dynamically in a function.  Any Ideas how to do this?

Here's an example of my code:

```
// UWP C# Code
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;

namespace GridNineExperiment
{    
    public class Hamburger : Button
    {    
        //static Size txsize = /* Default Font Size of Button, ie. Height and Width of Font Character*/

        // Change using txsize to calculate X,Y,Height,Width
        static GeometryCollection DataHamburger = new GeometryCollection
        {
            new RectangleGeometry {Rect = new Rect{X = 0, Y = 0, Width = 20, Height = 5 }},
            new RectangleGeometry {Rect = new Rect{X = 0, Y = 10, Width = 20, Height = 5 }},
            new RectangleGeometry {Rect = new Rect{X = 0, Y = 20, Width = 20, Height = 5 }},
        };

        static Path PathHamburger = new Path
        {
            Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White),
            Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
            StrokeThickness = 1.0,
            Data = new GeometryGroup { Children = DataHamburger } 
        };

    public Hamburger()
    {
        Content = PathHamburger;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you define _"Default Font Size of Button"_?

Comment: `Button.FontSizeProperty.DefaultMetadata.DefaultValue`

Comment: Based on what Clemens said and adjusting for UWP:          static double height = (double)Button.FontSizeProperty.GetMetadata(typeof(double)).DefaultValue;  No Idea if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you shouldn't make button Content properties static because you can only make one instance of the Button.  However, this is the solution that worked for me:

```
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;

namespace GridNineExperiment
{
    public class HamburgerButton : Button
    {
        public HamburgerButton()
        {
            // Default Font Height of Button
            double H = (double)Button.FontSizeProperty.GetMetadata(typeof(double)).DefaultValue;

            double A = H / 5;

            GeometryCollection DataHamburger = new GeometryCollection
        {
            new RectangleGeometry {Rect = new Rect{X = 0, Y = 0*A,  Width = 20, Height = A/2 }},
            new RectangleGeometry {Rect = new Rect{X = 0, Y = 2*A,  Width = 20, Height = A/2 }},
            new RectangleGeometry {Rect = new Rect{X = 0, Y = 4*A,  Width = 20, Height = A/2 }},
        };

            Path PathHamburger = new Path
            {
                Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
                Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
                StrokeThickness = 1.0,
                Data = new GeometryGroup { Children = DataHamburger }
            };

            Content = PathHamburger;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the **real** FontSize of any control, try this:

```
double fontSize = new TextBlock().FontSize;
```